# Marking a packagist package as abandoned in favor of a new location

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I'm going to be taking over a fairly popular PHP package under a github organisation. It's going to move from its previous location, and as a result the composer package name will be out of date.

I know it's possible to mark a package abandoned on packagist (See fabpot/php-cs-fixer) and forward it to a new one, but I'd like to make sure I know what I'm getting into so that the transfer can go smoothly.

I haven't been able to find anything about this on packagist or google.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/).

1. Log in as the user that published the package
2. Navigate to the package page
3. Click the button "Abandon"
4. Optionally enter a replacement package
5. Click "Abandon Package"

[image: Screenshot of screen with Abandon button]
[image: Screenshot of form to specify replacement package]

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't until I made the replacement package that I noticed the obvious bright orange button :)